# Alternative to the ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate subtotals in a separate line, but I cannot use ROLLUP or CUBE (because not allowed). I use SQL server 2008.
There is an other way to get follow results? thanks in advance!

`SELECT   deptno, empno, SUM (sal)
  2      FROM emp_test
  3  GROUP BY ROLLUP (deptno, empno);`

```
DEPTNO      EMPNO   SUM(SAL)
```

---

```
    10       7782      20000
    10       7839      10000
    10                 30000
    20       7566       5950
    20       7788       6000
    20       7902       6000
    20                 17950
    30       7698      20000
    30       7699      20000
    30                 40000
                       87950
```

Comment: I get this but I'm not admin: "The CUBE() and ROLLUP() grouping constructs are not allowed in the current compatibility mode.  They are only allowed in 100 mode or higher."

Comment: For the moment I cannot communicate with DBA

Comment: that essentially means you are not using SQL Server 2008 (or indeed 2005). Ask your DBA why the compatibility mode cannot be >> 90 << or higher

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918039/grouping-sets-display-subtotals-in-other-specific-column/ except there you say you're on SQL 2005: answer is the same in either case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try is using the `GROUPING()` function on the column.  This function returns 1 if it is part of the `GROUPING SETS` subtotals, and 0 if it is a regular column. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544(SQL.90).aspx

I included the sample data I tested with.  Remove the first `WITH emp_test AS ()` when you use the select statement.

My test data:

```
WITH emp_test AS
(
   SELECT 10 AS DEPTNO, 7782 AS EMPNO, 20000 AS sal
   UNION ALL SELECT 10, 7839, 10000
   UNION ALL SELECT 20, 7566, 5950
   UNION ALL SELECT 20, 7788, 6000
)
```

Actual query below:

```
SELECT deptno, empno
   , CASE
      WHEN GROUPING(empNo) = 1 THEN null
      ELSE SUM(sal)
     END as sum_salary
   , CASE
      WHEN GROUPING(empno) = 1 THEN SUM(sal)
      ELSE NULL
     END AS SubTotal
FROM emp_test
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (DeptNo, Empno), (DeptNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2008 you could consider [Grouping sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) instead?

For your case I think it would be:

```
SELECT deptno
,empno
,SUM(sal) as sum_salary
FROM emp_test 3 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
((DeptNo,Empno),())
```

But I only have 2005 so can't test it!

Comment: I've tried but I don't now how to use it, could you give me an example? thx

Comment: Try GROUPING SETS ((Deptno,Empno),(Deptno),()) instead - I didn't see that you also wanted subtotals for each department initially!

Comment: it is possible to display subtotals in other specific column?

Comment: It should be - can you give an example of what you'd want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

you rather write a procedure using Cursor to obtain similar result.

Comment: why not, but could you give me an example to obtain the above results plz?